# How to use WHERE NOT EXISTS query to avoid duplicate entry using $wpdb to save in custom table?

Tags: wpdb, sql

I am new to worpress database and stuck on checking duplicate entry of user email.
I would like to convert the following sql query in $wpdb

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO trip_rate (id, trip, rating, r_name, email, title, review) 
  SELECT  '', '$trip', '$rating', '$name', '$email', '$title', '$review' 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT email FROM trip_rate WHERE email='$email' AND trip='$trip')";


if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
    echo 'Review saved';
}
else{
    echo 'You have already reviewed this trip!';
}
```

My new code to convert it into WordPress

```
 <?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
$trip = $_POST['trip'];
$rating = $_POST['rating'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$review = $_POST['review'];

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->dmtable = $wpdb->base_prefix . 'trip_rate';
$my_part_ID = (bool)$wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT COUNT(r_email) FROM {$wpdb->dmtable}
                WHERE r_email = %d AND trip = %d LIMIT 1",
        $email, $trip
    )
);

if ($my_part_ID){
    echo"already reviewed";
}
else{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert('sb_trip_rate',array('trip'=>$trip, 'rating'=>$rating, 'r_name'=>$name,'r_email'=>$email, 'title'=>$title, 'review'=>$review,),array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s','%s'));
    }

}
?>
```

It keeps on saving values to table in spite of email field being unique

Comment: Is this your database table? Might want consider making the email column unique.

Comment: The code works perfectly in php... i am trying to convert it into wordpress sql statement to save in my custom table in database

Comment: If a columns needs to be unique, you should set it that way in the table. WordPress or not.

Comment: @JacobPeattie can you please review the new code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WHERE NOT IN is what you need.

$sql = "INSERT INTO trip_rate (id, trip, rating, r_name, email, title, review) 
  SELECT  '', '$trip', '$rating', '$name', '$email', '$title', '$review' 
  WHERE (trip_rate.email)
NOT IN (
  SELECT email FROM trip_rate WHERE email='$email' AND trip='$trip')";